# Create a histogram of that plots the frequency of 256 grayscale intensities JAVA

Tags: java, colors, histogram

I am having trouble creating a java class that takes the name of a picture file as a command-line argument, converts the picture to grayscale, and uses StdDraw to plot a histogram of the frequency of occurrence of each of the 256 grayscale intensities.

I have the portion that converts the picture to grayscale completed but am having trouble plotting the frequency of the 256 gray scale intensities. I'm not exactly sure how to proceed this. Here is my code

```
package grayscale;



import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.Picture;
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw;
import java.awt.Color;


    public class Grayscale {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            {

                Picture pic = new Picture(args[0]);
                int[] freq = new int[1000];

                for (int i = 0; i < pic.height(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < pic.width(); j++) {
                        Color color = pic.get(i, j);
                        Color gray = Luminance.toGray(color);
                        pic.set(i, j, gray);

                        Color c = pic.get(i, j);

                        int r = c.getRed();
                        int g = c.getGreen();
                        int b = c.getBlue();

                        if (r == c.getRed()) {
                            freq[r]++;
                        }
                        if (g == c.getGreen()) {
                            freq[g]++;
                        }
                        if (b == c.getBlue()) {
                            freq[b]++;
                        }


                        if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                            StdDraw.setXscale(-1, pic.width());
                            StdDraw.setYscale(0, pic.height());
                            StdDraw.setPenRadius(.5 / pic.width());
                            for (int k = 0; k < pic.width(); k++) {
                                StdDraw.line(k, 0, k, freq[k]);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    pic.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```